# Saving same data from parent model into children - Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm a bit confused about this, I don't seem to find the exact answer to this problem, not sure about which approach will be safer to do this.

I have a parent model, and 2 child models, I'm using django forms, what I want, is to fill the 2 child models whenever the parent is field, I mean, they look like this:

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField()
    field2 = models.CharField()
    field3 = models.CharField()

class Child1(Parent):
    pass

class Child2(Parent):
    pass
```

Since I don't want/need to create new fields on the child classes, everything is going to be inherited from the parent one, I can use the parent's fields on admin or forms without problems.

But what I actually want, is whenever the `Parent` fields are filled and saved into db, the same fields (or data) should be saved on `Child1` and `Child2` as well.

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: Because you are specializing your parent model, usually you want to create objects from the child models, doing this will allow you to access these object as instances of both parent and child models.

Comment: But if you create an object from the parent model, django will not be able to know weather this created object is of type child1 or child2.

Comment: More formally in OOP the following assumption: (type(child_obj) == Parent) is true, but this assumption: (type(parent_obj) == SomeChild) is false.

Comment: You could probably use an approach that works just as well for your purposes without duplicating (triplicating?) data, bloating your db and causing headaches down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution is override the `save` method, for example:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import model_to_dict

class Parent(models.Model):
    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    field2 = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    field3 = models.CharField(max_length=5)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.pk and self.__class__.__name__ == 'Parent':
            Child1.objects.create(**model_to_dict(self))
            Child2.objects.create(**model_to_dict(self))
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

but you should to understand, that after execute such code you will get triple instances inside the parent model:

```
for _ in range(4): 
    Parent.objects.create(field1='dsad', field2='aa', field3='dd')
```

and:

```
Child1.objects.count()
4
Child2.objects.count()
4
```

but

```
Parent.objects.count()
12
```

Comment: Although this solution syntactically correct, but it's semantically wrong as it violate the core concepts of OOP.

Comment: i don't think so, because life is more than OOP

Comment: Ok, but the whole idea of OOP is bringing life to coding, for example in OOP instead of saying variable and operations we say attribute, behavior.